# Maven site - querydsl-codegen-utils:pom:5.0.0 not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-data-jpa

When using maven site I get this error :

> com.querydsl:querydsl-codegen-utils:pom:5.0.0 was not found in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced

Looking more into the error I find :

> Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: com.querydsl:querydsl-codegen-utils:pom:5.0.0 failed to transfer from https://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/release during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of spring roo repository has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact com.querydsl:querydsl-codegen-utils:pom:5.0.0 from/to spring roo repository (https://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/release): Access denied to: https://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/release/com/querydsl/querydsl-codegen-utils/5.0.0/querydsl-codegen-utils-5.0.0.pom

Here my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>///</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>///</name>
    <description>///</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.5.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.13.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.214</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.23.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>31.1-jre</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf.tool</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlworker</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.13.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox-tools</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.26</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
            <version>2.64.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0-M3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
                            <processor>com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.0</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- Use the latest released version:
                          https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin/ -->
                <version>1.11.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <nodeVersion>v4.6.0</nodeVersion>
                    <workingDirectory>src/frontend</workingDirectory>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install node and npm</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <nodeVersion>v15.4.0</nodeVersion>
                            <npmVersion>7.3.0</npmVersion>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm install</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>install</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm run build</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>run build</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-build-folder</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/frontend/build</directory>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                            <outputDirectory>target/classes/static</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I've tried to go around the error, but found nothing. Hope someone can help,
thanks!

Comment: have you tried to change artifactId from /// to a word, also name has /// these may generate errors.

Comment: @ozkanpakdil I changed it for privacy. In my real pom.xml it is not ///. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. I downloaded the project https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/tree/QUERYDSL_5_0_0 and after running maven clean install of the project querydsl-codegen-utils it provided the following output:

```
[INFO] Installing ${HOME}/querydsl-QUERYDSL_5_0_0/querydsl-codegen-utils/target/codegen-utils-5.0.0.jar to ${HOME}/.m2/repository/com/querydsl/codegen-utils/5.0.0/codegen-utils-5.0.0.jar
```

So there is no artifact that matches querydsl-codegen-utils. I think the problem comes from the pom file of the module querydsl-bom. The artifact name  must be codegen-utils unstead of querydsl-codegen-utils.

A dirty workaround is to download or clone this project and change the artifactId of the module querydsl-codegen-utils querydsl-codegen-utils then mvn clean install or deploy to a local/remote repository

Comment: If the error is in the project files of the library it's best to also report that on Github so they can fix that.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I'll try your method to go around. Did you do it to run maven site on one of your project without the error ?

Comment: Yes it helped me to fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that spring boot is using `querydsl-bom` which has defined the wrong library artifact id. It has defined the id as

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
      <artifactId>querydsl-codegen-utils</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

whereas the exact library that has to be present is

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
      <artifactId>codegen-utils</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

Reference:- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.querydsl/querydsl-bom/5.0.0

Issue is fixed in querydsl-bom but never released a new version for it https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/commit/c589757291d4f53e6148dae3227bed111c2f740f